# What can be used to automate audio plugins using python?

Tags: python, audio, pyautogui

Writing in python
Is there a way to automate by opening a audio plugin like a DAW(Abelton Live) and adjusting parameters on that plugin? I see that there are tools like using pyautogui but wondering if there is anything else that can be used?

I tried using pedalboard but that seems to be able to load a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use MIDI to get you started:
https://www.midi.org/specifications/developer-white-papers

Almost all DAWs out there support MIDI input to control parameters like pan and level. Look for either "MIDI learn" or "MIDI mapping" to link a parameters of a plugins to received MIDI messages:
[MIDI Map Mode in Ableton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiShS.png) <- Everything in blue can be mapped to MIDI

Usually MIDI devices hook up via USB or the old DIN-5 ports. So you want to use a virtual MIDI device on the same machine instead.

Mido - MIDI Objects for Python is just the right library for that:
https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/